# Workaround for importing spark implicits everywhere

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0, implicits

I'm new to Spark 2.0 and using datasets in our code base. I'm kinda noticing that I need to `import spark.implicits._` everywhere in our code. For example:

```
File A
class A {
    def job(spark: SparkSession) = {
        import spark.implcits._
        //create dataset ds
        val b = new B(spark)
        b.doSomething(ds)
        doSomething(ds)
    }
    private def doSomething(ds: Dataset[Foo], spark: SparkSession) = {
        import spark.implicits._
        ds.map(e => 1)            
    }
}

File B
class B(spark: SparkSession) {
    def doSomething(ds: Dataset[Foo]) = {
        import spark.implicits._
        ds.map(e => "SomeString")
    }
}
```

What I wanted to ask is if there's a cleaner way to be able to do

```
ds.map(e => "SomeString")
```

without importing implicits in every function where I do the map? If I don't import it, I get the following error:

> Error:(53, 13) Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.

Comment: Updated my answer with some additional information. Don't hesitate to ask if you have any follow-up questions.

Comment: After a long time I found a more convenient method to do this. Added it to the answer below.

Answer (score 10):

Something that would help a bit would be to do the import inside the `class` or `object` instead of each function. For your "File A" and "File B" examples:

```
File A
class A {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    def job() = {
        //create dataset ds
        val b = new B(spark)
        b.doSomething(ds)
        doSomething(ds)
    }

    private def doSomething(ds: Dataset[Foo]) = {
        ds.map(e => 1)            
    }
}

File B
class B(spark: SparkSession) {
    import spark.implicits._

    def doSomething(ds: Dataset[Foo]) = {    
        ds.map(e => "SomeString")
    }
}
```

In this way, you get a manageable amount of `imports`.

Unfortunately, to my knowledge there is no other way to reduce the number of imports even more. This is due to the need to the `SparkSession` object when doing the actual `import`. Hence, this is the best that can be done.

---

**Update:**

An even more convinient method is to create a Scala `Trait` and combine it with an empty `Object`. This allows for easy import of implicits at the top of each file while allowing extending the trait to use the `SparkSession` object.

Example:

```
trait SparkJob {
  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.
    .master(...)
    .config(..., ....) // Any settings to be applied
    .getOrCreate()
}

object SparkJob extends SparkJob {}
```

With this we can do the following for File A and B:

File A:

```
import SparkJob.spark.implicits._
class A extends SparkJob {
  spark.sql(...) // Allows for usage of the SparkSession inside the class
  ...
}
```

File B:

```
import SparkJob.spark.implicits._
class B extends SparkJob {
  ...    
}
```

Note that it's only necessary to extend `SparkJob` for for the classes or objects that use the `spark` object itself.

Comment: Excellent answer, so sad you got zero upvotes in two years. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

You could re-use existing SparkSession in each called method.. by creating local val inside method -

```
val spark: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.active
```

And then

```
import spark.implicits._
```

Working fine for me so far..