# How to correctly use import spark.implicits._

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have different functions in my Scala Spark program (simplified code):

```
def func1(spark: SparkSession, inputpath: String, calc_slot_udf: UDF) : DataFrame = {
    import spark.implicits._

    val df = spark.read.parquet(inputpath)

    valresult = df.withColumn("time_slot", calc_slot_udf($"tt"))

    return result
}

def func2(df: DataFrame, c: String) : DataFrame = {
    import spark.implicits._

    result = df.filter($"country" === c)

    return result
}
```

Also, I have the main function where I create `SparkSession` `spark`. Then I pass `spark` to other functions. However, since I use `filter($"...")` and other similar functions, I should use `import spark.implicits._` inside each function.

Is there any way to avoid repeating `import spark.implicits._` inside each function?

Comment: Duplicate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45724290/workaround-for-importing-spark-implicits-everywhere

also this one is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39151189/importing-spark-implicits-in-scala